# Manage large array on a file java

Tags: java, arrays, memory

I am writing an android app that requires a lot of memory, sometimes my double arrays gets to sizes of Megabytes and i somehow need all that data available at feasible time. I see that most of the time i just cant have them all on RAM. so i am looking for a java API that lets me create arrays that are managed on the file system rather than on RAM, the api should give me the ability to act as if it was a real array, eg, it must have get(int index) set(int index) and length() methods that does the same as if it was a real array.

anyone know of a good library that does something like that? or maybe suggest a better approach?

Comment: hmm, you may find switching to an actual database may be your best bet imho. I like H2 Database, it's written in pure java. It's an embedded database meaning it stores itself on the filesystem. It can do in-memory database, but this isn't persistent like you want.

Comment: otherwise, you could try creating an array container object which represents part of the large array, chain these container objects together like in a double linked list, and then serialize those objects to the filesystem.

Comment: seems to me that using a database for that is a bit of a waste isnt it?

Comment: not if it solves your problem the easiest...  :-)

Comment: @SnakeDoc yeah i could implement it myself in some way, but i was wondering if there's already someone who already solved this better then i can do myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the [`MappedByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) and it's [`asFloatBuffer()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asFloatBuffer%28%29) methods.

Comment: This doesnt help as android doesnt come with java 7 :(

Comment: @SnakeDoc nice! ok i will try that!

Comment: @OfekRon You just go the `FileChannel` -> `MappedByteBuffer` -> `FloatBuffer` route and add some error handling where needed. If you have more specific questions, just post a new question about them. I don't know if memory-mapped IO is available on Android. You question was not tagged Android, so..

Comment: i dont get how you transform a double array to a filechannel to be accessed by this mappedbytebuffer thing

Comment: @OfekRon You have to start with the `FileChannel.open(..)` and work your way from there.